# What is the ^[ sign in vim and how to remove it

Tags: linux, vim

I store some script output into a txt file. And when I open the txt file using vim or nano, I see the following.

```
^[[34m[i]^[[0m It seems like you have not updated the database for some time.
^[[32m[+]^[[0m Started: Tue Sep 12 05:46:44 2017
```

And I'm expecting the following.

```
[i] It seems like you have not updated the database for some time.
[+] Started: Tue Sep 12 05:46:44 2017
```

What is these extra symbols? How can I remove it in vim, or at least hide it? Thanks

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/7695/how-to-make-vim-display-colors-as-indicated-by-color-codes

Comment: It seems to be some [VT100 escape secuences](http://www.termsys.demon.co.uk/vtansi.htm) to set colors of the text.

Comment: OK it is VT100 codes as mentioned by @Someprogrammerdude. And I found a related question to hide(properly display) those symbols. https://stackoverflow.com/a/18684985/6228451